# Pass numeric matrix of rgb color values to chartJSRadar() in R

Tags: r, matrix, rgb, chart.js, radar-chart

I'm using `chartJSRadar()` function in the radarchart package from Chart.js. I want to customize the colors but I can't figure out how to pass the RGB values.  My data looks like this:

```
         Ncount        Strong         Exclusive
 Define     69             19                 6
  Align     74              9                 1
 Refine     84             28                 0
 Assign     77             12                 3
```

Basically I want a different color for each column.  [The docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/radarchart/radarchart.pdf) say to pass colors as a matrix of RGB colors in `colMatrix`. So I've tried-

```
chartJSRadar(radarcounts, maxScale = 90, addDots = F, lineAlpha = 0, 
             colMatrix = matrix(c("FF0000","00FF00","0000FF"))
```

But this just makes all the polygons gray.  I can't find working examples of the `colMatrix` parameter. What should the `colMatrix` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a way to format RGB values in a matrix format acceptable to Radarchart.  I used `grDevices::col2rgb` to do so -

```
c <- grDevices::col2rgb(c("orange","blue", "black"))
```

Then I just dropped `c` into the argument list -

```
chartJSRadar(radarcounts, maxScale = 90, addDots = F, lineAlpha = 0, colMatrix = c)
```

There is probably a better way to do this, but this is what I found.